# FFMPEG filter is not implementing

Tags: java, android, video, filter, ffmpeg

I'm using FFMPEG for applying and saving the file to the specified path. Since I'm new to FFMPEG so I've followed [this](http://writingminds.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java/) link to import the FFMPEG libraries inside my project.

FFMPEG libraries are working fine inside my project. Now I've followed [FFMPEG Commands](http://androidwarzone.blogspot.in/2011/12/ffmpeg4android.html) link for applying filters using commands. **For now i'm using vintage filter command to check whether it is working or not**

I've followed [FFMPEG Project in Android](https://github.com/bhuvnesh123/FFmpeg-Video-Editor-Android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/videoeditor/bhuvnesh/com/ffmpegvideoeditor/activity/MainActivity.java) link to apply the filters and save it to my storage path.

I'm using a file from my storage path to apply filter for the same and saving them inside the specified path. The problem is that the command is implementing(doubtful) but no file is getting saved with the filters, **nor I get any exception or any error in my logcat**. I"m very doubtful whether what is being left to get the desired result.

This is my code where I'm using the FFMPEG for applying filters and saving them in the specified path.

**FilterAcitivity.java**

```
public class FilterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ArrayList<String> videoReceiveddata = null;

private EPlayerView ePlayerView;

private StringBuilder stringBuilder;

private DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory;
private ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory;

private Button play,stop,noneFilter,faded,noir,instant;

private FFmpeg fFmpeg;

private int choice = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_filter);

    Bundle videoExtras = getIntent().getExtras();

    videoReceiveddata = videoExtras.getStringArrayList("sendData");
    Log.e("RECEIVED_VIDEO====", videoReceiveddata.toString());

    stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for(String path : videoReceiveddata){
        stringBuilder.append(path);
    }

    //laoding the ffmpeg binary files
    loadFFMEPGBinary();


    BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
    TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory =
            new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
    TrackSelector trackSelector =
            new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);
    // Measures bandwidth during playback. Can be null if not required.
    DefaultBandwidthMeter defaultBandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
    // Produces DataSource instances through which media data is loaded.
    dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(getApplicationContext(),
            Util.getUserAgent(getApplicationContext(), "TestApp"), defaultBandwidthMeter);
    // Produces Extractor instances for parsing the media data.
    extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
    // This is the MediaSource representing the media to be played.
    MediaSource videoSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(Uri.parse(stringBuilder.toString()),
            dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);


    // 2. Create the player
    final SimpleExoPlayer player =
            ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(getApplicationContext(), trackSelector);
    player.prepare(videoSource);

    ePlayerView = (EPlayerView) findViewById(R.id.ePlayer);
    ePlayerView.setSimpleExoPlayer(player);
    ePlayerView.onResume();



    play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playButton);
    stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopButton);
    faded = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fadedFilter);
    noneFilter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.noFilter);
    noir = (Button) findViewById(R.id.noirFilter);
    instant = (Button) findViewById(R.id.instantFilter);

    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            MediaSource videoSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(Uri.parse(stringBuilder.toString()),
                    dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);
            player.prepare(videoSource);
            player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
        }
    });

    stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            player.stop();
        }
    });

    noneFilter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            choice = 1;
            ePlayerView.setGlFilter(new GlFilter());
        }
    });

    faded.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            choice = 2;
            ePlayerView.setGlFilter(new GlSepiaFilter());
            Log.e("Filter Applied",ePlayerView.toString());
            Log.e("Filter Applied====",stringBuilder.toString());

        }
    });
}

//loading binary of ffmpeg
private void loadFFMEPGBinary() {
    try {
        if (fFmpeg == null) {
            Log.e("TEST=====", "ffmpeg : null");
            fFmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(this);
        }

        fFmpeg.loadBinary(new LoadBinaryResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure() {
                showUnsupportedExceptionDialog();
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                Log.d("TESTAPP====", "ffmpef : coorect loaded");
            }
        });
    } catch (FFmpegNotSupportedException e) {
        showUnsupportedExceptionDialog();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("TESTAPP=====", "Exception not supported" + e);
    }
}

private void showUnsupportedExceptionDialog() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(FilterActivity.this)
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
            .setTitle("Not Supported")
            .setMessage("Device Not Supported")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    FilterActivity.this.finish();
                }
            })
            .create()
            .show();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.filter_menu,menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.save:
            if(choice == 1){
                addThatFilter();
            }else if(choice == 2){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No filter",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

private void addThatFilter() {

    String savingPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString()
            + "/FilterVideo.mp4";

    String complexCommand = "ffmpeg -y -i"+ stringBuilder.toString() +"-strict experimental -vf " +
            "curves=vintage -s 640x480 -r 30 -aspect 4:3 -ab 48000 -ac 2 -ar 22050 -b 2097k -vcodec " +
            savingPath;

    execFFMPEGBinary(complexCommand);
}

private void execFFMPEGBinary( final String complexCommand) {

    try{

        fFmpeg.execute(new String[]{complexCommand}, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler(){

            @Override
            public void onFailure(String message) {
                Log.e("Failed with output", message);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String message) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Success!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        });
    }catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e){
        //do nothing
    }
} }
```

Comment: Are you getting callback inside onscuccess?I don't think so..Remove ffmpeg from complex command..And can you try creating savingpath as done in sample project inside Movies Directory?

Comment: @BhuvneshVarma I've made some changes in my command line as per you said and now I'm able to apply some filter and saving the file as well. Now the problem is the **output is coming in the rotated form.** Why is that? I don't think so that I've applied some rotation.